# how to stop script from running when drives are full

Tags: bash

I have a script that will run and fill up a drive without remorse. I want to set a highwater mark of 90%.
I created a cron that will check if the script is installed and if so if running.

```
#!/bin/sh
COUNTER=$(df -Ph | grep -vE '^tmpfs|cdrom' | sed s/%//g | sed 1d | awk '{ if($5 > 90) print $1;}' | wc -l)
if [[ -e /var/stats/automation/stats-collection.pl ]]; then
 _running=$(ps faux | grep stats-collection.pl | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
 if [[ $_running -eq 1 ]]; then
 echo "Stats running"
 if [[ $COUNTER -gr 0 ]]; then
 echo "Drive found above highwater mark. Ending Platform stats."
 kill $_running
 fi
 else
 echo "Platform stats not running."
else
 echo "Platform stats not found"
fi
```

How would I combine the benefits of a continuously running cron job to run and stop the offending script from running. Would a while loop be the answer?

Comment: The offending script probably has a main loop. You could let it `df -Ph <devicelist>` itself and gracefully terminate or `sleep 60` if the disks it uses are too full. If it does proper logging, you could use logrotate instead.

Comment: Just FYI: `grep | sed | sed | awk | wc` is something of an anti pattern. You can do all of it with a single `awk` much more efficiently than creating 5 processes.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Noted.